# Send file stream using axios in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, axios

I have a node.js server and client using graphql. I need to upload file from a client, send it to the node server and then forward this file to another service, lets name it X.
When i upload file to node.js server i can get a readable stream of file using apollo graphql API and it works fine.
But when i try send this stream to X using axios, on X i can read only one chunk of the file.

Here's code from my node.js server:

```
const { createReadStream } = await file;
const stream = createReadStream();

axios.post('http://localhost:7000', stream, {
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  maxContentLength: Infinity
});
```

And here is a receiver (X server) controller code

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('final.csv');
req.pipe(writeStream);
res.send('Hello');
```

In `final.csv` file i can see only small part of data i send. I want to be able to send files up to 1GB size.

Comment: What headers of a request did you receive on X server?

Comment: @Anatoly 

accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',

'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

'user-agent': 'axios/0.21.0',

host: 'localhost:7000',

connection: 'close',

'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'

Comment: You should try to set `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` in order to send a stream